# How to make objects collide just once?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have objects that look like square.(have collider and rigidbody)

I want those squares to make a sound when I hit these squares with an object. But just once(once for scene). If I hit one of the squares again, ıt shouldn't make sound. How could I do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Add a simple flag .. disable its Collider component .. destroy its collider component and/or this script which is listening to the collisions  ... Etc

Comment: Thanks. But What is the best solution ? Should I add boolean like D.Dorion showed belong, or destroy it's collider component ? @derHugo

Comment: If you destroy the Collider component, the GameObject won't collide with other colliders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `OnCollisionEnter()` method is called you can check if a bool variable was set to true.

```
hasCollided = false;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
    if (!hasCollided){
        // Play sound
        hasCollided = true;
    }        
}
```

Comment: This, but instead of using bool variable, just destroy collider. That will save resource as well.